# Export orders from Woocommerce turn to 0 items

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

All my orders items change to zero (0) when I export from my wordpress dashboard. When I import to the new database, it changes to all to 0. Before it was 2 items, 1 items for some orders. What I did is Tools -> Export -> Orders -> Download export file.

Comment: Are you using [Order/Customer CSV Export](https://www.woothemes.com/products/ordercustomer-csv-export/) and [Customer/Order/Coupon CSV Import Suite](https://www.woothemes.com/products/customerorder-csv-import-suite/) for this? I'm having the same situation, have you found a solution for this so far?

Answer (score 1):

"WooCommerce Order Export Import Plugin helps you to easily export and import orders in your store. This plugin lets you import/export all orders with line item details. " From [WordPress Plugin Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-import-export-for-woocommerce/)

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your child function.php

```
add_filter ( 'wc_order_is_editable', 'majemedia_add_order_statuses_to_editable' ); 

function majemedia_add_order_statuses_to_editable () { 
    return TRUE; 
}
```

now you can edit orders... try editing orders and let know if any issues